# --insecure-skip-tls-verify doesn't work with kubefed join

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to add a clusters to federation using kubefed join :
this is the federation kube config file :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://k8s-apiserver.cluster.local:8443
  name: kubernetes
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://172.16.1.4:32471
  name: federation
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://139.54.130.49:32046
  name: kubernetes-s1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: kubectl
  name: default-context
- context:
    cluster: federation
    user: federation
  name: federation
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: kube-system
    user: kubectl
  name: kube-system-context
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes-s1
    namespace: default
    user: kubernetes-admins1
  name: kubernetes-admin-s1
current-context: federation
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: federation
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
    token: e7506989-42eb-11e8-bf70-fa163eb593a3
- name: federation-basic-auth
  user:
    password: e7506937-42eb-11e8-bf70-fa163eb593a3
    username: admin
- name: kubectl
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: kubernetes-admins1
  user:
    token: eyJhbGciOiJSUz............
```

i run this command : kubefed join site-1 --host-cluster-context=default-context --cluster-context=kubernetes-admin-s1 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true, the cluster is created but with offline status , is not reacheable ;
I'm using token bearer to reach the api server of the target cluster;
where am I going wrong ?

```
kubectl describe clusters
Name:         site-1
Namespace:    
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  federation.kubernetes.io/cluster-role-name=federation-controller-manager:federation-site-1-default-context
              federation.kubernetes.io/servive-account-name=site-1-default-context
API Version:  federation/v1beta1
Kind:         Cluster
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2018-04-22T17:37:40Z
  Resource Version:    1347
  Self Link:           /apis/federation/v1beta1/clusters/site-1
  UID:                 daf922d2-4653-11e8-aded-f225b0c7c174
Spec:
  Secret Ref:
    Name:  site-1-w4vv6
  Server Address By Client CID Rs:
    Client CIDR:     0.0.0.0/0
    Server Address:  https://139.54.130.49:32046
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Probe Time:       2018-04-22T18:09:43Z
    Last Transition Time:  2018-04-22T17:37:42Z
    Message:               cluster is not reachable
    Reason:                ClusterNotReachable
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Offline
Events:                    <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/federation/blob/HEAD/pkg/federation-controller/cluster/cluster_client.go#L81), that message means exactly what it says:

The cluster is not reachable, because the cluster endpoint `https://139.54.130.49:32046` is not reachable from the controller.

So, just check if the endpoint is correct and available for connecting from the controller.

Comment: yes, the federation controller use tls authentication to access the api server of the target cluster, how to tell him like the federation api server to skip tls authentication because i'm using token to access to the target api server

Comment: There is no way to use insecure connection. `insecure-skip-tls-verify` only disable the verification of TLS keys, but not disable TLS itself.